# Which placeholder for fscanf?

Tags: c

I have a file that I open which has a bunch of lines with data like this:

```
 0x804ae1c: W 0x0000000c
```

I'm trying to extract the 3 different strings into 3 different variables but I'm having problems getting values from the 2nd and third token.

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
 unsigned long address;
 unsigned long address2;
 char* readWrite;
 fscanf(traceFile, "%lx %s %lx\n", &address, line, &address2)
```

I get the pointer for the first line. i.e:

```
 804ae1c
```

but after that the other 2 variables do not get the proper things assigned to them. I tried changing line to a char but to no avail. How should I proceed fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: try `fscanf(traceFile, "%lx: %c %lx\n", &address, &readWrite, &address2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to allocate storage, rather than just declaring a `char*`. If you are reading only a single character, a simple `char` is sufficient.

As BLUEPIXY's comment mentions, you need to account for the extra `:` character in your string. Here is a test program that shows this (reads from stdin).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long address;
    unsigned long address2;
    char readWrite;
    int retVal;

    retVal = scanf("%lx: %c %lx", &address, &readWrite, &address2);
    if (retVal == 3) {
        printf("%lu: %lu %c\n", address, address2, readWrite);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even for learners, code that uses the return value of `scanf()` to detect success is preferable.